# Pear is not recognized as internal or external? issue

Tags: php, installation, pear

I have installed pear but when run from my command prompt i get 
"`pear is not recognized as internal or external command`" . can anyone tell me how to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: what is your development environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the pear bin directory to your $PATH variable. For windows: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Answer (score 6):

One after I am having the same issue. But this is what I did:

1. Create a folder called PEAR in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8`
2. Downloaded latest go-pear.phar from **http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar** to the above folder
3. cd to the PEAR then Ran command `php go-pear.phar`